# Удаление файла

Tags: файлы

Правда ли, что при удалении файла на самом деле стирается только первый байт?

Comment: В ФС он помечается стёртым. Так работает удаление в корзину. Он либо стёрт, либо не стёрт (статус как бы). shift+delete тоже не трёт файл, а так или иначе меняет что-то в таблице с информацией о файлах.
А первый байт файла - что там?)

Comment: Илья, в подобных вопросах желательно уточнять, о поведении какой OS Вы спрашиваете.

Comment: OS тут не причем. Играет роль файловая система.

Comment: linux

Answer (score 2):

Даже после быстрого форматирования файл можно восстановить без особых проблемм (исключение составляет, когда на место, где он хранился была записана информация), что уж говорить о его удалении. Как было верно замечено удаляется только информация в каких секторах жесткого диска он хранился, сама информация лежит там до тех пор, пока не будет перезаписана другой. Это же присуще и для карт памяти. Низкоуровневое форматирование предполагает перезапись всех секторов и тут, конечно, уже не спасти ничего. Поиграйтесь с программкой R-Studio, например, много интересного найдете :-)

Comment: Зависит от файловой системы. Есть драйвера ФС, который файл физически трут при его удалении. В минусах при этом имеем более низкую скорость работы с ФС.

Comment: @gecube, еще добавлю, что если каждый раз стирать файл полностью, то это уменьшает продолжительность жизни финтчестера.

Comment: Это не является критическим моментом. Для NAND - возможно, для винчестера - сомнительно. Все равно эти сектора будут рано или поздно переписаны. Тем более, если кол-во свободного места на НЖМД стремиться к нулю (как обычно и бывает). Плюс можно немного упростить выделение места под файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Файл не удаляется, а только ссылка на файл)